# flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not parse the arguments in "create_app(config="test.cfg")"

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Good Day!

This dont work with flask run:

```sh
export FLASK_APP='mypkg:create_app(config="test.cfg")'
flask run
```

The relevant error msg:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not parse the arguments in "create_app(config="test.cfg")".
```

On gunicorn, i can run:

```sh
gunicorn 'mypkg:create_app(config="test.cfg")'
```

There any way to this work on `flask run`? I just don't want make a custom runner.

Comment: Why don't u export FLASK_APP to your main flask file ?

Comment: I can create a custom runner(ex: a custom function for initialization for tests), but this will not allow me to change the parameters quickly. Surprisingly, gunicorn that would be to use in production and that I do not need to change parameters, supports this very easily .....

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you can:

```
export FLASK_APP=mypkg:create_app("test.cfg")
```